# Show that $x_n = \sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right)^2} - \sqrt n$ is a bounded sequence.

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, upper-lower-bounds

> Let $n\in \mathbb N$ and:
>   $$
> x_n = \sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right)^2} - \sqrt n
> $$
>   Show that $\{x_n\}$ is a bounded sequence.

This sequence appears a bit tricky because it involves harmonic series. Below are steps I take.

**Lower bound:**

$$
\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right)^2} \ge \sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{k}{k}\right)^2} = \sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n1}=\sqrt{n}\implies\\
\implies x_n \ge \sqrt n - \sqrt n \ge 0
$$

Lower bound is simple.

**Upper bound:**
To get rid of radical lets use Cauchy-Schwarz (note the below is incorrect as shown in Zvi's answer):
$$
\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right)^2} \le \sqrt{\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right)\right)^2} =\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right) = n+\sum_{k=1}^n{1\over k} = n + H_n
$$

So this doesn't show $x_n$ is bounded above. I've tried another approach:

$$
\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right)^2} - \sqrt n = \frac{\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right)^2 - n}{\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right)^2} + \sqrt n}
$$
Consider nominator:

$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right)^2 - n=n+\sum_{k=1}^n{2\over k}+\sum_{k=1}^n{1\over k^2}-n = \sum_{k=1}^n{1\over k^2} + \sum_{k=1}^n{2\over k}
$$

For denominator:
$$
\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right)^2} + \sqrt n = \sqrt{n + \sum_{k=1}^n{1\over k^2}+\sum_{k=1}^n{2\over k}} + \sqrt n
$$

So $x_n$ is:
$$
x_n = \frac{\sum_{k=1}^n{1\over k^2} + \sum_{k=1}^n{2\over k}}{ \sqrt{n + \sum_{k=1}^n{1\over k^2}+\sum_{k=1}^n{2\over k}} + \sqrt n }
$$

But i don't see how to proceed from this point. What else could i try? How to show $x_n$ is bounded above?

Please note the precalculus tag.

Comment: Where does that $\pi^2/6$ come from? Your sequence seems does not involve the infinite sum $\sum_1^\infty 1/k^2 = \pi^2/6$.

Comment: @xbh Right! my bad, the sum involves only $n$ terms, i will update the post

Comment: Nominator is at most $\frac{\pi^2}{6}+2\ln(n)+2$. The denominator is at least $\sqrt{n}$. This means we can bound sequence from above by $\frac{\frac{\pi^2}{6}+2\ln(n)+2}{\sqrt{n}}$, converging to $0$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jakobian gave a very good hint.  I am giving somewhat sharper bounds for $x_n$.  Note that the OP incorrectly used the  Cauchy–Bunyakovsky–Schwarz inequality.  Indeed, when applied correctly, we get
$$\sqrt{n}\left(x_n+\sqrt{n}\right)=\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n1^2}\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right)^2}\geq \sum_{k=1}^n1\cdot\left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right)=n+H_n,$$
where $H_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k$ is the $n$th harmonic number.  That is,
$$x_n\geq \frac{H_n}{\sqrt{n}}.$$

For the upper bound, the OP got 
$$x_n=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^2}+2H_n}{\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right)^2}+\sqrt{n}}.$$
We can show that $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k^2}$ is bounded above by $2$ via
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k^2}<1+\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{1}{k(k-1)}=1+\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)<2.$$
However, a sharper upper bound is $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k^2}<\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$. Also, $$\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right)^2\geq \sum_{k=1}^n1^2=n.$$ This proves that
$$x_n<\frac{\frac{\pi^2}{6}+2H_n}{\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n}}=\frac{H_n}{\sqrt{n}}+\frac{\pi^2}{6}\left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}\right).$$
(You can replace $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ by $2$ if you want a precalculus solution.)

That is, we have
$$\frac{H_n}{\sqrt{n}}\leq x_n<\frac{H_n}{\sqrt{n}}+\frac{\pi^2}{6}\left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}\right).$$
So, $x_n$ has the asymptotic behavior of $\frac{H_n}{\sqrt{n}}\approx \frac{\ln n}{\sqrt{n}}$.  But to show that $x_n$ is bounded, we don't need to know that $H_n\approx \ln n$ (well, to be even more precise, $H_n\approx \gamma+\ln n$, where $\gamma$ is the Euler–Mascheroni constant).  Clearly,
$$\frac{\pi^2}{6}\left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}\right)\leq \frac{\pi^2}{6}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right).$$
Furthermore,
$$H_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}\leq \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}<\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{2}{\sqrt{k}+\sqrt{k-1}}=2\sum_{k=1}^n(\sqrt{k}-\sqrt{k-1})=2\sqrt{n}.$$
Hence,
$$x_n<\frac{2\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n}}+\frac{\pi^2}{6}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=2+\frac{\pi^2}{6}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)<\infty.$$
Again, replace $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ by $2$ if you don't want any non-precalculus knowledge in the proof.  So, you would get $x_n<3$ for all $n$.

Comment: I've been working through your answer. There is one bit i still don't get. That is $\sqrt n(x_n + \sqrt n) = \dots$. Could you please explain why we need this exact expression and where is it derived from? Also why is $\sum_{k=1}^n {1\over \sqrt k} < \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{2}{\sqrt k + \sqrt{k-1}}$? The rest seems clear to me. Thank you very much for taking your time, your answer is very helpful. I want to accept it once i fully grasp the details

Comment: I've understood the second part from my comment, you have multiplied and divided by $2$. $\frac{1}{\sqrt k} = \frac{2}{2\sqrt k} = \frac{2}{\sqrt k + \sqrt k}< \dots$

Comment: The point is I wanted to get the term $\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n1^2}\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right)^2}$ to use the CBS inequality.  But by definition of $x_n$, this expression equals $\sqrt{n}(x_n+\sqrt{n})$.

Comment: Great! Got it now, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Even if $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^2 = n + 2H_n + H_n^{(2)}$ involves (generalized) harmonic numbers, it is pretty straightforward to notice$^{(*)}$ that $H_n=O(\log n)$ and $H_{n}^{(2)}=O(1)$ as $n\to +\infty$, hence

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^2 = n\left(1+O\left(\frac{\log n}{n}\right)\right),\tag{1}$$

$$ \sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^2} = \sqrt{n}\left(1+O\left(\frac{\log n}{n}\right)\right)=\sqrt{n}+O\left(\frac{\log n}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\tag{2}$$
and the wanted limit is zero.

$(*)$ $H_n \leq 1+\int_{1}^{n}\frac{dx}{x}=1+\log(n)$ and $H_{n}^{(2)}\leq 1+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k(k+1)}\leq 2$.

Answer (score 0):

You have, using that $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$, 
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right)^2 - n=\sum_{k=1}^n \left[ \left(1+\frac1k\right)^2-1\right]
=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1k\left(2+\frac1k\right)\leq3\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k.
\end{align}
Using the comparison with the integral we get 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k\leq1+\int_1^n\frac1t\,dt=1+\log n. 
$$
Then
$$
\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right)^2} - \sqrt n = \frac{\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right)^2 - n}{\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right)^2} + \sqrt n}\leq\frac{3(1+\log n)}{\sqrt n}.
$$
Since $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{3(1+\log x)}{\sqrt x}=0$, the continous function $f(x)=\frac{3(1+\log x)}{\sqrt x}$ is bounded on $[1,\infty)$. Thus there exists $C>0$ with 
$$
\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right)^2} - \sqrt n \leq\frac{3(1+\log n)}{\sqrt n}\leq C. 
$$